# Put calls in a queue and waiting for updating the state in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, promise, async-await

I've got a function that I run in the `forEach` loop in the child component, the function has to filter the data and update the state with the result. 
The problem is that when I iterate the function with a loop it running all at the same time and within this, the state will not update properly with data. 
The question is how to implement it better, probably there is a way with Promise or async /await or maybe something simpler that will make a work. As needed to put in the queue and wait until the state will be updated.

Simplified code is here
component child

```
this.props.data.forEach((item, i) => {
    this.props.update(item);
});
```

component parent

```
function update(data) {
    let filtered = this.state.data.filter(item => item.uid !== data.uid);
    this.setState({data: filtered});
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve with this behaviour? Why not just update the state after you're running your loop?

Comment: @DanielAndrei Sorry, have updated the example, so the state should be updated with filtered variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand well you need something like this:

```
update = () => {
    let filtered = this.state.data.filter(x => this.props.data.every(y => x.uid !== y.uid))
    this.setState({
        data: filtered
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. 
I need to wait until state will be updated and then run next function in the loop or I need to create a queue inside the update function and wait for each filter result.  Because now it just re-saves the filtered variable and only last function in the loop works right.

Comment: setState(updater, [callback]) is an async function. So you can check does state updated with callback:
this.setState({
            data: data
        }, () => {
            this.stateUpdated();
        });

Also check this:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: have no chance to answer, thanks for commenting out here. I didn't find any better solution as just use setTimeout so inside the iterator put 
`setTimeout(() => this.props.update(item))`

Answer (score 2):

Why not iterating through your array in your parent component?

Child:

```
this.props.update(this.props.data); // pass the entire array
```

Parent:

```
function update(data) {
    let filtered = data.map(d=> {
        return this.state.data.filter(item => item.uid !== d.uid);
    }
    this.setState({data: filtered});
}
```

Comment: You have to change the logic a little bit so it fits your needs. I don't know what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: I can't pass an array into the update function because it can accept only an object. It's because it uses globally and should be a possibility to update only one uid.